# Does svn:ignore affect the repository directly?

Tags: svn

I work in a massively shared code base. And while synchronizing my working copy with the repository, I have a ton of unwanted files showing up.

If I ignore a file or directory with `svn:ignore`, does that get propagated to the repository? Or is it limited to my local working copy?

I have Googled for a specific answer and read through subversion documentation, but no success. Am I missing something obvious there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn:ignore` is a property, and [properties are propagated to repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html):

> In addition to versioning your directories and files, **Subversion
>   provides interfaces for adding, modifying, and removing versioned
>   metadata on each of your versioned directories and files**. We refer to
>   this metadata as properties, and they can be thought of as two-column
>   tables that map property names to arbitrary values attached to each
>   item in your working copy. Generally speaking, the names and values of
>   the properties can be whatever you want them to be, with the
>   constraint that the names must contain only ASCII characters. **And the
>   best part about these properties is that they, too, are versioned,
>   just like the textual contents of your files.** You can modify, commit,
>   and revert property changes as easily as you can file content changes.
>   And the sending and receiving of property changes occurs as part of
>   your typical commit and update operations—you don't have to change
>   your basic processes to accommodate them.